# Binary multiplication in Galois Field GF(2^8)

Tags: finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials, cryptography

I am working on a project (high school), and I need to explain the process of AES MixColumns for one of the parts.

I am trying to show an example of the matrix multiplication in MixColumns that uses GF(2^8), but I think I did it wrong, and I am not sure where I went wrong. I was wondering if someone could take a look at where my mistake was and explain it to me. Here is what I have written:
[image: My work]

I think the mistake may be somewhere in the multiplication of the polynomials (the last step in the picture), but I might be mistaken and it happened earlier.

Note: there's [this YouTube video](https://youtu.be/WPz4Kzz6vk4?si=vTQXfVsfnEZNPohP&t=227) that explains MixColumns in GF(2^3) (since the converted hex to binary is 8 digits), but on all the documentation for AES, they use Rijndaels finite field.

Thanks!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In last step of your calculation:
[image]
I think the $x^4$ term is erroneous
My calculation:
$(x^4+x^3+x+1)+x^7+x^6+x^5+x^4+x^2+x$
$=x^7 + x^6 + x^5 + 2 x^4 + x^3 + x^2 +2 x+ 1$
$=x^7 + x^6 + x^5  + x^3 + x^2 + 1$

Comment: Otherwise, it looks fine? Thanks, stupid oversight on my part.